# How to Fire event on scrollBar visible in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, scrollbar, scrollpane

At the time of scroll bar visible or occur I want to fire an event. Till now what I've done is

```
private ScrollBar getVerticalScrollbar() 
    {
        ScrollBar result = null;
        for (Node n : scrollPaneID.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) 
        {
            if (n instanceof ScrollBar) 
            {
                ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;
                if (bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) 
                {
                    result = bar;
                }
            }
        }       
        return result;
    }  
ScrollBar bar = getVerticalScrollbar();
```

through this I can check if the scroll bar is appear or not

```
if(bar.isVisible()) 
 {

 }
```

but it works only after the scrollbar is visible. My requirement is fire event when scrollbar is appear

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a ChangeListener to visible property.Something like below but this will fire every time its visibility changes so put your logic inside the changed method very carefully according to your requirement

```
result.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean, final Boolean aBoolean2) {
            System.out.println("Scrol Pane visible");

        }
    });
```

Comment: I had tried this listener too. But I am wondering that **scrollPaneID.visibleProperty()** listener is not listening anything but **scrollPaneID.vvalueProperty() ** is working but It doesn't fullfill my requirement